# How to migrate approval process and steps by DataLoader?

Tags: configuration, salesforce

I want to upload Approval Process and Steps along with approval/rejection actions via data loader. Could you please tell me the steps to do so?

Comment: The following answers the question:

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22952/is-it-possible-to-setup-approval-process-and-steps-via-data-loader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approval processes are configuration and metadata. The dataloader is for meant for the import/export of record data which isn't the same.

Metadata can be migrated(deployed) with change sets or the meta data api, but i believe not all parts of approval processes are supported by these mechanisms yet (you can try). You may need to manually copy the same configuration to different orgs, or create instructions to do so.